# How to get value of date time picker bootstrap in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have tried to print out the date-time picker value in the `console` but nothing works.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sm" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">{{ __('messages.assetmgt.warrantyeffectivedate') }}</label>
  <div id="myDate" class="col-sm-6 input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
     <input class="input-sm form-control"  type="text" name="awEffectiveDateWeb" id="awEffectiveDateWeb" readonly/>
     <span class="input-group-addon try dateTimePickerButton" id="awEffectiveDate"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
  </div
</div>
```

JS

```
var value = $("#myDate").datetimepicker("getDate");
console.log(value);
```

DateTime picker

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bootstrap-timepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
    });
});
```

My expected result is when the DateTime value was changed, the value of the date-time picker will be printed on the console.

Comment: Check this , you might to use the onchange event for that : https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Better to initialize datepicker on input element rather than div

```
$('#awEffectiveDateWeb').datetimepicker({
     format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
});
```

And you can use datepicker on change function

```
$('#awEffectiveDateWeb').on('dp.change', function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time sir but what i got 4 field of timepicker how do i initialise it?